# Unexpected behaviour when reading parameters from standard input

Tags: regex, perl, scripting

```
sub Solution{
    $matchflag=0;
    $occurence=0;

    #OUPTUT [uncomment & modify if required]
    my $ind=index($m,$p);


    if ($ind!=-1){
       $matchflag=1;
    }

    $occurence= () = $m =~ /$q/g;


    print("$matchflag\n");
    print($occurence);
}

#INPUT [uncomment & modify if required]
$n=<STDIN>;
$m=<STDIN>;
$p=<STDIN>;
$q=<STDIN>;


Solution();
```

Hello can someone tell me what's wrong with this code?
It gives me the following output.

```
6
naman
nam
n
0
1
```

Clearly the 0 should be 1, because nam exists in naman string. and also 1 should be 2 as n occurs twice in the string.

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: You need to tell us what your inputs are. Please [edit] your question and include how you are calling this code.

Comment: You should ALWAYS use `use strict; use warnings;`. You have numerous scoping issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP probably meant the code be as follows

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $n = input();
my $m = input();
my $p = input();
my $q = input();

Solution();

sub input{
    my $input = <STDIN>;

    chomp $input;

    return $input;
}

sub Solution{
    my $matchflag=0;
    my $occurence=0;

    #OUPTUT [uncomment & modify if required]
    my $ind=index($m,$p);


    if ($ind!=-1){
       $matchflag=1;
    }

    $occurence= () = $m =~ /$q/g;


    print("Match flag: $matchflag\n");
    print("Ocurance:   $occurence\n");
}
```

Output

```
6
naman
nam
n
Match flag: 1
Ocurance:   2
```

Comment: So in a language like Java or C, we need to pass arguments during function call so that the function can access those variables. Here, you do not pass arguments while calling the function. What's going on here?

Comment: Function may or may not have any arguments, and it can or may not return anything. Some function can for example optimize database, verify that procedure finished successfully and do not return anything. Some functions may have arguments, do some operations with them and then return result -- for example _calculator_ operation as add, subtract, multiply, power.

Answer (score 6):

When you read from `<STDIN>` you need to remove `\n` newline char at the end of string,

```
chomp for
    $n=<STDIN>,
    $m=<STDIN>,
    $p=<STDIN>,
    $q=<STDIN>,
;
```

You may also want to consider better scoping by using `my` lexicals instead of global variables, and some checks which make life easier like `use strict; use warnings;`

Comment: `chomp($n=<STDIN>)` or `$n=<STDIN>; chomp($n)` works equally well.

Comment: Also, is there a way to avoid writing <STDIN> so many times while taking such a simple input?

Comment: Yes, foreach and variable aliasing. chomp($_=<STDIN>) for $n, $m;